# FORMTEXT Appearing in Word File Name Generated from Protected Form-Field Value and BookMark for VB Script

Tags: vb.net, templates, ms-word

I am using the following VB Script in a Word 2010 Doc saved as a Microsoft Word Macro-Enabled Template that is protected for form fields:

```
Sub SaveWithBkMarkedText()
    'This code saves the Word file using the bookmark value for Maintenance Memo.
   'The file is also saved to a folder in KnowHow for files related to this template.
   Dim FileName As String
   FileName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("mmn").Range.Text
   'Use the C:\ code when saving the file locally
   ActiveDocument.SaveAs "C:\Download\TemplatesFolders\" & FileName & ".doc"
   MsgBox "Your Draft has been saved to KnowHow's Release Documentation site." & _
      &vbCrLf & "The file name uses the MM that you included earlier: " & FileName, _
       vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Draft Saved to Minerva"
End Sub
```

The value entered into the Form Field for a FORMTEXT legacy-form object uses the Bookmark  as the file name.  Example, if the user enters 12345 as the value, the file is saved using this value as the filename: 12345.doc.  This worked fine until a week ago when the filename is now being Prefixed with FORMTEXT 12345.doc.  I have tried using this same VB script in older versions of Word on a different machine, and created from a NEW Template with the script added in from scratch, and the same issue is appearing on that machine as well.  Prior to this, I was able to update my template with NO problem, but now I can't update this one FORMTEXT field without it affecting the whole file.  I can update any other FORMTEXT in the template that does not use the Bookmark value as the file name, and it works.  Also, I have tried changing the Bookmark Reference to another FORMTEXT object, as well as saving the file as a .DOCX and the same problem occurs regardless.   What is causing the FORMTEXT to appear in the filename?

Comment: Something like this can happen if the bookmark "covering" the FORMTEXT field has been repositioned. However, right now I can only get the foloowing behaviours: the bookmark either "covers" the field code (e.g. " FORMTEXT ") or the result+some surrounding text. Not quite the same as your result. What happens if you re-apply the bookmark to the FORMTEXT field? Typically you can do that by going into the Properties and re-applying them, but it may be safer to remove the existing bookmark before re-applying it. I have seen similar reports of this behaviour recently, but I do not know the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You have to un-protect the document (template) and then make the VBA programming. Once it is done, then you can protect it again (for filling forms) and you will not see the "FORMTEXT" in the filename when you run the macro.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To the OP, did you resolve this issue? I'm now having the same problem, I'm using form field text with bookmarks and using VB.net to get the bookmark.text which is now prefixed with FORMTEXT, just using a bookmark on it own and its OK, no prefix. I'm going to try and remove the first 9 characters from the result using code, a workaround, yes but it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Know this is an old thread but ran into same issue. As a workaround...
Replace FORMTEXT with null "". In OP circumstance:

```
Dim FileName As String
   FileName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("mmn").Range.Text 
   FileName = Replace(FileName, "FORMTEXT ", "")
```

Not a "fix" for the issue or elegant but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Simply delete current bookmark and add a new one. If that does not work than instead of using the following:

```
FileName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("mmn").Range.Text
```

try using:

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="mmn"
Filename = Selection.Text
```

Comment: Sure. I'm using a sub just like you. I'm combining a bookmark with a date. When I used the text in the bookmark to combine it with my date I got the same FORMTEXT as a prefix as you. When i deleted the bookmark i was using and added it again it seemed to work. If that does not work for you, you cna try the following:                                                           
     Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="yourBookmark"
     Filename = Selection.Text